# Dash Filtering For Numeric Columns

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to use the code below in order to allow user to filter columns. The problem i sthat I cannot filter the columns with numerical values. How can I solve this issue? I was thinking to find column type, but it was not in the code

````
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')

df['id'] = df['country']
df.set_index('id', inplace=True, drop=False)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.RadioItems(
        [{'label': 'Read filter_query', 'value': 'read'}, {'label': 'Write to filter_query', 'value': 'write'}],
        'read',
        id='filter-query-read-write',
    ),

    html.Br(),

    dcc.Input(id='filter-query-input', placeholder='Enter filter query'),

    html.Div(id='filter-query-output'),

    html.Hr(),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df.columns
            # omit the id column
            if i != 'id'
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
        filter_action="native"
    ),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id='datatable-query-structure', style={'whitespace': 'pre'})
])


@app.callback(
    Output('filter-query-input', 'style'),
    Output('filter-query-output', 'style'),
    Input('filter-query-read-write', 'value')
)
def query_input_output(val):
    input_style = {'width': '100%'}
    output_style = {}
    if val == 'read':
        input_style.update(display='none')
        output_style.update(display='inline-block')
    else:
        input_style.update(display='inline-block')
        output_style.update(display='none')
    return input_style, output_style


@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'filter_query'),
    Input('filter-query-input', 'value')
)
def write_query(query):
    if query is None:
        return ''
    return query


@app.callback(
    Output('filter-query-output', 'children'),
    Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'filter_query')
)
def read_query(query):
    if query is None:
        return "No filter query"
    return dcc.Markdown('`filter_query = "{}"`'.format(query))


@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-query-structure', 'children'),
    Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'derived_filter_query_structure')
)
def display_query(query):
    if query is None:
        return ''
    return html.Details([
        html.Summary('Derived filter query structure'),
        html.Div(dcc.Markdown('''```json
{}
```'''.format(json.dumps(query, indent=4))))
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
````

Is there any way to handle this issue? Alternatively, where is the column type included in this script? I took it from Dash website.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to filter it. Please, try to give clear example.

Comment: @Hamzah When I run this code, I see datatables. Just below the headers, user can write a number or string to filter datatable. But, this code does not work with numbers.

Comment: Could you please add an example for this query for non-numeric column?

Comment: It works very well even with numbers, what queries did not work with you?

Comment: For example, I want to filter 708573 value in pop column. When I write 708573 in filter, nothing shows in the datatable. But, there is a row containing that value. I do not know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write your own filter, you should enclose the column name with {}. For example, in order to get the value `708573` from `pop` column, you should write it as:

```
{pop} = 708573
```

But if you write your filter under a specific column, in this case, you only need to write `= 708573`

Please look in the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/filtering#advanced-filter-usage)  to familiarize yourself more to the filtering syntax.

Comment: is there anyway to change to filter the date without = sign? It would be confusing for the end user to filter numerical columns with = at the begiinning, and string type columns without = sign